# Display corresponding details of user when selected from list

Tags: android

I have developed a screen where a no. of people from the database are displayed in a list view. I want to display the profile page of the selected person. So my question is how to bind each detail of the selected person like name, contact, etc. to the profile page which I have created? Will I have to call the getById API in the onItemClickListener?

Here's the **edited code**:-

```
public class Test extends AppCompatActivity {

    List<Genie> genieList;
    GenieAdapter genieAdapter;


    TextView responseView;
    ProgressBar progressBar;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test);


        responseView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.responseView);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test);



        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(Test.this, "Blahblah", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();

            }
        });

    }


    class RetrieveFeedTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<Genie>> {

        private Exception exception;

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            responseView.setText("");
        }

        protected List<Genie> doInBackground(Void... urls) {


            GenieService genieService = new GenieService();
            return genieService.getAll();
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(List<Genie> genies) {
            if (genies == null) {
                new ArrayList<Genie>(); // "THERE WAS AN ERROR"
            } else {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                Log.i("INFO", genies.get(0).name);

                List<String> rows = genies.stream().map(genie -> getRow(genie)).collect(Collectors.toList());

              genieAdapter=new GenieAdapter(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.genie_list, genies);

                ListView list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listViewMain);
                list.setAdapter(genieAdapter);

                list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(Test.this, "" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                        if (position == 1) {
//                            startActivity(new Intent(Test.this, viewGenie1.class));
//                    }
                }
            });

            list.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Test.this, viewGenie1.class);
                    intent.putExtra("name", "%s");
                    intent.putExtra("add", "%s");
                    intent.putExtra("phn", "%s");
                    intent.putExtra("sal", "%s");
                    intent.putExtra("lea", "%s");
                    startActivity(intent);
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
            }
        }

        private String getRow(Genie g) {
            return String.format("%s, %s, %s, %s, %s", g.name, g.salary, g.contact, g.paid_leaves, g.address);
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the viewGenie1.class:-

```
public class viewGenie1 extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    TextView name;
    EditText address, contact, salary, leaves;
    Button attendance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_genie1);

        name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txName);
        address = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txAddress);
        contact = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txContact);
        salary = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txSalary);
        leaves = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txLeaves);


        Button update=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btUpdate);
        update.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button delete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.delete);
        delete.setOnClickListener(this);

        Button attendance = (Button) findViewById(R.id.attendance);
        attendance.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showAtt();
            }
        });
        String value = "";
        if (getIntent().hasExtra("name")) {
            String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
            String add = getIntent().getExtras().getString("add");
            String phn = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phn");
            String sal = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sal");
            String lea = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lea");
        }

        name.setText(value);
        address.setText(value);
        contact.setText(value);
        salary.setText(value);
        leaves.setText(value);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(viewGenie1.this);
        builder.setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete records?");
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                new deleteTask().execute();
                Toast.makeText(viewGenie1.this, "Genie deleted..!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(viewGenie1.this, navDrawer.class));


//                GenieService genieService=new GenieService();
//                genieService.delete(2);
//                Log.d("Information", String.valueOf(genieService.delete(2)));
                // Log.i("INFO", genies.get(0).name);
                // startActivity(new Intent(viewGenie1.this,Test.class));
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert=builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private class deleteTask extends AsyncTask {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
            GenieService genieService = new GenieService();
            return genieService.delete(6);
        }
    }

    public void showAtt() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, viewAbsentee.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Here's the xml file of the profile page I have created with **hard coded values** but want to display the **actual values** from the local mysql database using an API call:-

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bcak"
    tools:context="com.codionics.geniem.AddGenie"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="313dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:background="@drawable/gradientbackground"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="117dp"
                android:layout_height="117dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/genie" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:text="Abc"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="21sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="115dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="175dp">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="2">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Contact"
                        android:textColor="#f000"
                        android:textStyle="bold"
                        android:textSize="20sp" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txContact"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="123456789"
                        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Address"
                        android:textColor="#f000"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/txAddress"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:paddingTop="10dp"
                        android:text="Pune"
                        android:textColor="#3F51B5"
                        android:textSize="15sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="360dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_attach_money_black_24dp" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Paid leaves : "
                android:textColor="#303F9F"
                android:textSize="27dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txLeaves"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="  5" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_money" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:text="Salary : "
                android:textColor="#303F9F"
                android:textSize="27dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/txSalary"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text=" 5000"
                android:textColor="#123" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btUpdate"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstylegradient"
        android:text="Update Genie"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstylegradient"
        android:text="Delete Genie"
        android:textColor="#fff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/attendance"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonstylegradient"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:text="Attendance" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I want to display the details in the a profile page like this:-

[profile page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oxycj.png)

Comment: pass your list item data through intent to next activity and use it to display

Comment: Not working. Nothing happens after clicking on the item in the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please pass the value in Intent using `putExtra()`

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Test.this, viewGenie1.class);
intent.putExtra("key","Value"); //Key must be unique and value should be the value which you want to pass to viewGenie1 class.
startActivity(intent);
```

In viewGenie1 class you can get the value like this

```
String value="";
    if(getIntent().hasExtra("key")) {
        value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("key");
    }
```

Please replace

```
String value = "";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("name")) {
        String name = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        String add = getIntent().getExtras().getString("add");
        String phn = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phn");
        String sal = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sal");
        String lea = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lea");
    }

    name.setText(value);
    address.setText(value);
    contact.setText(value);
    salary.setText(value);
    leaves.setText(value);
```

To

```
String mName = "",mAdd="",mPhn="",mSal="",mLea="";
    if (getIntent().hasExtra("name")) {
        mName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("name");
        mAdd = getIntent().getExtras().getString("add");
        mPhn = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phn");
        mSal = getIntent().getExtras().getString("sal");
        mLea = getIntent().getExtras().getString("lea");
    }

    name.setText(mName);
    address.setText(mAdd);
    contact.setText(mPhn);
    salary.setText(mSal);
    leaves.setText(mLea);
```

Comment: The list of no people in database is generated but when I click on a person in the list nothing happens.

Comment: have you use onItemSelected listener or not?

Comment: So the intent will have to be passed in the onItemSelectedListener wil it?

Comment: please update ur code as well..So that i can check it.

Comment: please check this listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        //please Add the Intent which you want to trigger on item click in listview
                    }
                });

Comment: So add the whole intent and put.Extra() in onItemClick??

Comment: And what will be inside the onItemSelectedListener?

Comment: jiust remove this listener

Comment: Not making any difference.:(